# Replace missing Btrfs RAID-1 device - btrfs replace and balance?

Tags: raid, btrfs, raid1

Recently, I replaced a device on two Btrfs RAID-1 filesystems because  disks needed to be replaced.

I did it like this:

```
mount -o noatime,degraded /dev/sda3 /mnt/tmp
btrfs fi show /dev/sda3
btrfs replace start -B 1 /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt/tmp 
btrfs replace status /mnt/tmp 
btrfs fi show /dev/sda3
btrfs fi show /mnt/tmp
btrfs scrub start -B /mnt/tmp
mount -o noatime /dev/sda3 /mnt/tmp
ls /mnt/tmp
btrfs fi show /mnt/tmp
umount /mnt/tmp
```

That means:

- I mounted the device because `btrfs replace` only seems to support replacing a device on a mounted filesystem
- I checked with `btrfs fi show` what device id is missing (`1` in this example)
- I thus replaced the missing device `1` with the `nvme0n1p3` device on the new disk
- the final show looked good and the scrub didn't complain
- and umount and mount (without degraded) after the procedure worked fine
- no errors were reported by these commands or in the kernel log

However, after I've now removed the old leg (i.e. /dev/sda3) the filesystem can't be mounted, anymore:

```
mount -o noatime,degraded /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt/tmp
mount: /mnt/tmp: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p3, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

fails and yields:

```
Dec 22 09:41:34 BTRFS info (device nvme0n1p3): allowing degraded mounts
Dec 22 09:41:34 BTRFS info (device nvme0n1p3): disk space caching is enabled
Dec 22 09:41:34 BTRFS info (device nvme0n1p3): has skinny extents
Dec 22 09:41:34 BTRFS warning (device nvme0n1p3): devid 2 uuid f9c9c081-0fdc-4b61-8329-c1addb51e3fe is missing
Dec 22 09:41:34 BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p3): failed to read chunk root
Dec 22 09:41:34 BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p3): open_ctree failed
```

So my expectations were that:

- a `btrfs replace` command is sufficient to replace a missing device on a RAID-1 btrfs filesystem
- especially, `btrfs replace` would copy all data/metadata from the remaining to the newly added device

Since this didn't work I'm not sure anymore whether  a `btrfs replace` is always sufficient.

Does a `btrfs replace` perhaps needs to be followed by an explicit balance?

For example by something like this?

```
btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1,soft -mconvert=raid1,soft /mnt/tmp
```

### Additional info:

- so the overall objective was to replace both legs of RAID-1 btrfs filesystems, i.e. do the replacements in 2 steps - first the left leg then the right leg
- Replacements done on Fedora 33 (kernel 5.8.18-300.fc33.x86_64 and btrfs-progs-5.7-5.fc33.x86_64)
- Btrfs filesystems were created on Ubuntu 20.04
- `btrfs rescue chunk-recover` didn't help

Now the `btrfs fi show` reports:

```
btrfs fi show /dev/nvme0n1p3
warning, device 2 is missing
warning, device 2 is missing
bad tree block 934674432, bytenr mismatch, want=934674432, have=0
ERROR: cannot read chunk root
Label: none  uuid: 1c1a03db-38c2-4b08-a2ec-47d200f98b0a
    Total devices 2 FS bytes used 196.62MiB
    devid    1 size 1.00GiB used 758.38MiB path /dev/nvme0n1p3
    *** Some devices missing
```

I don't know why the warning is repeated two times.

### Second Example

On the same system, replacing a missing disk in another Btrfs RAID-1 filesystem failed in a similar way.

Replacement procedure:

```
mount -o noatime,degraded /dev/mapper/new-root-1 /mnt/tmp
btrfs fi show /mnt/tmp
btrfs replace start -B 1 /dev/mapper/new-root-0 /mnt/tmp 
journalctl -fk
btrfs fi show /mnt/tmp
btrfs scrub start -B /mnt/tmp
umount /mnt/tmp
```

Mount fails after the other leg is removed:

```
mount -o noatime,degraded /dev/mapper/new-root-0 /mnt/tmp
mount: /mnt/tmp: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/new-root-0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Logged errors during mount:

```
Dec 22 09:57:12 BTRFS info (device dm-1): allowing degraded mounts
Dec 22 09:57:12 sos.lru.li kernel: BTRFS info (device dm-1): disk space caching is enabled
Dec 22 09:57:12 BTRFS info (device dm-1): has skinny extents
Dec 22 09:57:12 BTRFS warning (device dm-1): devid 2 uuid 3093e508-17e0-4f5c-af13-642954e6fd9b is missing
Dec 22 09:57:12 BTRFS warning (device dm-1): devid 2 uuid 3093e508-17e0-4f5c-af13-642954e6fd9b is missing
Dec 22 09:57:12 BTRFS info (device dm-1): bdev (efault) errs: wr 0, rd 8, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
Dec 22 09:57:12 BTRFS warning (device dm-1): chunk 69823627264 missing 1 devices, max tolerance is 0 for writable mount
Dec 22 09:57:12 BTRFS warning (device dm-1): writable mount is not allowed due to too many missing devices
Dec 22 09:57:12 BTRFS error (device dm-1): open_ctree failed
```

Missing device warning is repeated even four times here:

```
btrfs fi show /dev/mapper/new-root-0         
warning, device 2 is missing
warning, device 2 is missing
warning, device 2 is missing
warning, device 2 is missing
Label: none  uuid: 3e861d70-9a98-402d-8bbc-ddec6f869433
    Total devices 2 FS bytes used 62.81GiB
    devid    1 size 231.67GiB used 65.01GiB path /dev/mapper/new-root-0
    *** Some devices missing
```

Comment: So, metadata was also RAID-1, right?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, yes, I created the filesystems with `mkfs.btrfs --data raid1 --metadata raid1 /dev/... /dev/...`. In contrast to the other commands, I don't have the mkfs commands recorded in a history file, anymore. However, I have some notes that feature that form and I even created one filesystem also with the `--mixed` switch which makes `--metadata` mandatory. (If not specified the command fails.) Since I wasn't sure whether metadata also defaults to raid1 or not if one only specifies `--data raid1`, I explicitly also specified `--metadata raid1`.

Comment: You could also look at the output of `sudo btrfs filesystem usage /mnt/tmp`.  It should you  how the data/metadata is distributed on each device.

Comment: @rickhg12hs good tip. Will use it when I need to use btrfs replace again. However, since I can't mount the filesystems anymore I can't  call the usage command on those broken fileystems.

Answer (score 1):

Any data written while mounted degraded may end up stored with single or dup profile. The balance run ensures such data are also mirrored.